# abstract class or interface for classes in jenkins templating

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-template-engine

Is inheritance possible in a JTE library?
`maven/src/maven/MavenUtility.groovy`
`docker/src/docker/DockerUtility.groovy`

The above groovy classes have the following similarities.

```
class MavenUtility/DockerUtility implements Serializable {

   ArrayList command 
   def steps
   def config
   
   MavenUtility(steps,config){
   this.steps = steps
   this.config = config
   command = []  

  }
  
  //more methods to fill in the command variable

 def execute(){
   steps.sh command.flatten().join(" ")
 }

}
```

Can I put this in a parent class `Helper/src/helper/Utility.groovy`(somehow) and make the MavenUtility and DockerUtility inherit the properties and methods? Is that even possible in a library in jenkins templating?